# Are Activity/Fragment Transitions compatible with pre-Lollipop devices?

Tags: java, android, material-design, activity-transition, shared-element-transition

I'm trying to make an Activity Transition using Shared Elements on a pre-Lollipop device (4.x). Is it possible? So far, I'm trying this:

```
public class RewardDetail extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(imageView, TRANSITION_NAME);
    }

    ...

    public static void launch(ActionBarActivity activity, View transitionView, WelcomeReward detailData) {
        ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, transitionView, TRANSITION_NAME);
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, RewardDetail.class);
        intent.putExtra(PARAM_DATA, detailData);
        ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, intent, options.toBundle());
    }
}
```

called by:

```
@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
    int position = recyclerView.getChildPosition(v);
    WelcomeReward welcomeReward = data.get(position);
    RewardDetail.launch(WelcomeRewardActivity.this, v.findViewById(R.id.reward_view), welcomeReward);
}
```

But it results in a "regular" transition (no shared element). Any ideas?

**EDIT**

According to this video, it could be done:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhiPJByIMrM&index=8&list=WL

Is there a library already implementing this for pre Lollipop ?

Comment: If you are looking for a way to do it in pre-Lollipop, you can use this video as an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA (note that it requires much more work to implement, however).

Comment: There was a promising update in Support library 24.2.0 - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#24-2-0-api-updates with android.support.transition package but it is backported APIs for View-level only!

Answer (score 19):

No, Activity/Fragment Transitions are not possible on pre-Lollipop devices. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#startActivity(android.app.Activity,%20android.content.Intent,%20android.os.Bundle)):

> Start an activity with additional launch information, if able.
>
> In Android 4.1+ additional options were introduced to allow for more control on activity launch animations. Applications can use this method along with ActivityOptionsCompat to use these animations when available. When run on versions of the platform where this feature does not exist the activity will be launched normally.

See also George Mount's answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27344357/844882).

Comment: So... if the activity/fragment transitions are only possible in Lollipop, does this mean that some Google apps use the more complicated approaches (as you provided in the question's comment) to achieve the transition? I am really curious how Google calendar and Keep get it work in lower versions..

Comment: Google Calendar and Google Keep have probably implemented their own custom libraries for doing this... there is no official API that supports pre-Lollipop devices.

Comment: @Qianqian It certainly isn't impossible to achieve something similar to Fragment transitions in previous versions of the platforms... fragments are essentially just `View` containers, after all. But implementing such a feature might require reworking major parts of your application. On the other hand, it is impossible to implement Activity transitions on previous versions of the platform as they depend on the Render Thread which was added to the framework in Lollipop.

Comment: @AlexLockwood, from your quote, it looks like Activity launch animations should be possible in Android 4.1+

Comment: You can try implementing something yourself, but there are no backwards compatible libraries provided by Google.

Comment: @AlexLockwood my app is working fine in Lollipop but it seem to crash in the pre lollipop versions. Is this related or the app should atleast work without transitions in pre lollipop devices. The error log shows
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x10c000d

Comment: The app will crash if you try to use these APIs before lollipop.

Comment: That link in your post was replaced for a reason: [Blacklist the use of common link shorteners in posts](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313621).

Comment: [This is being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385606/6282576)

Answer (score 8):

You can check out this library for activity and fragment transitions for pre lollipop devices

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.albinmathew:PreLollipopTransition:1.1.2'
}
```

https://github.com/albinmathew/PreLollipopTransition

Answer (score 2):

Although the fancy Lollipop Activity/Fragment transitions are not available pre-Lollipop (without the use of a 3rd party library), you can still override the animation used to transition between activities.

Just before/after you start invoke startActivity() you can make a call to [Activity.overridePendingTransition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int, int)). When you leave your activity, call the same method.

Similarly you can use ActivityOptionsCompat to define a custom animation to use during a transition.

```
ActivityOptionsCompat opts =
    ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.in, R.anim.out);
startActivity(intent, opts.toBundle());
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a support library, but it does not support (all) transitions on Android versions below 5.0. There are however some alternatives:

> **Unofficial Compatibility libraries**
>  https://github.com/andkulikov/transitions-everywhere
>   https://github.com/takahirom/PreLollipopTransition
>   https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations
>
> **Android KitKat**
>  http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/11/new-transitions-framework/ and a
>   sample found in your SDK samples folder.

Posted earlier to a duplicate of this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27344471/1683141