# android 5 activity transition on lower api

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, activity-transition

Every time i search i came across this " android 5(L) activity transition only available on `API >= 21` .

that's fine but i can see some app like `QuickPic` and `google inbox` that use similar transition and **also** working on lower api, so how this app can do such a thing?

**what i have done?**

1) a lot of search:)

2) playing with `ActivityOptionsCompat` that only apply to api >= 21, like this:

```
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, transitionView, DATA.EXTRA_PASSED_JSON);
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, PhotoViewerActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(DATA.EXTRA_PASSED_JSON, json);
ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, intent, options.toBundle());
```

EDIT(question marked as duplicate): it's different from other question in this case, because i said there is other app that do this transition in lower api and i want to know how they do that.

Comment: @alex-lockwood in the future when you decide to singlehandly close a ticket for being a duplicate, please link to the duplicate post.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

We added a lot of stuff in Lollipop to make Activity Transitions work well. It is possible to do Activity Transitions manually (in earlier versions), but you will encounter problems in some cases and the return transition is likely going to work only in the simplest case. Chet Haase has a devbyte on this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA).

Animations between fragments were possible earlier, though the API isn't as easy to use as in Lollipop's Fragment Transitions.

We thought a lot about back porting transitions to earlier versions in the support library. It may still happen. If so, we should also be able to do something for Fragment Transitions.

Comment: in the recent update to Gmail app, we can see that the makeSceneTransitionAnimation is possible in pre-lollipop devices as well, can you please let me know how can we achieve this ?

Comment: good news foks it happens they have added it in v4 support lib take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/transition/package-summary.html

Answer (score 22):

Like you say yourself, the support library does not support (all) transitions on Android versions below 5.0. There are however some alternatives:

**Unofficial Compatibility libraries**
https://github.com/andkulikov/transitions-everywhere
https://github.com/takahirom/PreLollipopTransition
https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations

**Android KitKat**
http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/11/new-transitions-framework/ and a sample found in your SDK samples folder.

Comment: tnx, i think i can make this work.

Comment: with the library you linked i can use transition between 2 view in lower api but i can't figure out how to apply transition between 2 `activity`, can you hint me?

Comment: You can load the view of the second activity, then, perform an intent without animation. Ofcourse, this is more difficult when you next activity has different content.

Comment: I tried https://github.com/takahirom/PreLollipopTransition between two activities and its working. Do you have any idea if we can do transition of multiple elements using it?

Comment: I doesn't look like PreLollipopTransition supports multiple elements. You can try using a view container (e.g. a relativelayout) if you want to transfer multiple elements at once. You can try using the other library or filing this as a future suggestion to the library.